# CSS flex property doesn't work with Angular 4

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have the following CSS style (in the global stylesheet):

```
#container {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    max-width: 64rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In the plain HTML file, the container uses the full height of the window.
In my Angular 4 project, however, the flex property has literally NO effect. Why is that so? And how can I solve this?

Here is a JSFiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s2mw9nqe/2/)

This is how it should work. But when I move the HTML template to angular (split specific CSS into **component.css** files and global styles like `#container` to the global stylesheet) it doesn't work anymore. The container doesn't fill the whole width and just files the height the element has.

Comment: [The `flex` property should go on the children of `display:flex`, not the flex container itself.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-13)

Comment: The funny thing is that it works in plain html...

Comment: What works in plain html? ... post a working snippet showing that please

Comment: Is the output from Angular exactly the same as in plain HTML? Would be better if you could provide HTML for both cases and even the working snippet.

Comment: I will as soon as I'm back at work...

Comment: @Blazemonger flex is correct as the body has display: flex as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error...

The problem with flexbox is that if you have (angular) components in containers with `display: flex`, as they get loaded the `app-samplecomponent` tag remains and disturbs flexbox to do it's job.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Did you find a way round it?

Comment: Yeah I found (but did not use) an alternative. Checkout angular-flex by the angular itself. It may help you...